# Web API routing for non-REST services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm designing a webservice which has nothing to do with REST. It backs up a single-page application and currently must implement three simple methods:

```
public class ImportController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string[] Parse(string source) { ... }

    [HttpPost]
    public ConvertResponse Convert(ConvertRequest request) { ... }

    [HttpGet]
    public object GetHeaders() { ... }
}
```

It worked pretty well when I was using `Controller`, except for one thing: I needed to convert all returned JSON data to camelCase. I found a pretty reasonable solution on the web which used `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`, but it was only applicable to WebApi controllers since MVC controllers that return `JsonResult` always use `JavascriptSerializer` and ignore this configuration.

When I switched the base class to `ApiController`, the routing broke: `GetHeaders` works, but other methods return a `404` error!

My route configuration is as follows:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ImportParse",
    routeTemplate: "import/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Import" }
);
```

The successful request (AngularJS):

```
var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3821/';
$http.get(baseUrl + 'import/getHeaders').success( ... );
```

The unsuccessful request:

```
$http.post(baseUrl + 'import/parse', { source: 'test' }).success( ... );
```

Error:

```
message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:3821/import/parse'."
messageDetail: "No action was found on the controller 'Import' that matches the request."
```

How do I define the correct routing rules for those methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably Web Api is looking for a Parse action that supports HttpPost **and has object parameter.** Because you post object, but not a string, that is why you get 404.

To solve this problem try to send :

$http.post(baseUrl + 'import/parse', 'test').success( ... );

Comment: Thanks! I added a `ParseRequest` with `Source` field and now it works fine. Thank you!